# sed and quotation marks

Tags: text-processing, sed

I get data files that contain both of these (with the commas and the quotation marks)
`,"ncal",`
`,"NCAL",`
I want to replace all occurrences of `,"ncal",` with `,"NCAL",`

BUT, I want to leave alone
`,"Med Ofc Adm-Clncal Suppt Svcs",`
(A downstream process is case sensitive.)

I tried both of these:

```
sed -i 's/%ncal%/%NCAL%/g' /data/userinfo.csv

sed -i 's/\”ncal\”/\”NCAL\”/g' /data/userinfo.csv
```

What am I missing?  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried to specify what is the initial (^) and end ($) point of the regular expression evaluation?

Comment: odd quotes `”` (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK)

Comment: ... it should be as simple as `'s/"ncal"/"NCAL"/g'` (ordinary double quotes `"` are not special in sed, and the outer `'` single quotes protect them from the shell)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:
`sed -re 's/([^a-zA-Z ]ncal[^a-zA-Z ])/\U\1/g' /data/userinfo.csv`

*no test data available*

Function:
Find `ncal` where the character before and after is NOT in `a-z` nor `A-Z` , *(note trailing space, so excluding spaces too)*  keep those characters as match number 1 (what is inside the first and only parentheses in the search portion of the `s` command, and therefore denoted as `\1` in the replacement portion) and replace them with the `\U` => upper case version of the same.